# How can I execute cron task as a non-root user within the rails docker container?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, cron, infrastructure

I'm trying to use cron as a non-root user in the docker container.
The container already has rails application by the non-root user and I want to execute cron tasks as the same user while getting rails server running at the same time.
However, when I run `docker-compose up -d` I get an error saying **cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied**

So my question is if there is any way to execute cron task as non-root user in the container that has rails application. 
**Just so you know I tried not to use root account for a security reason.
Thank you in advance!**

Here is my dockerfile bedow
...

```
FROM ruby:2.5

RUN apt-get update -qq && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    nodejs \
    cron \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get clean

ENV \
 USER=new_user \
 GROUP=new_user \
 APP_ROOT=/var/www/new_user \
 HOME=/home/new_user \
 RAILS_PATH=./apps/server/new_user

RUN groupadd $GROUP && \
 useradd -g $GROUP $USER

RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT && \
 mkdir -p $HOME

WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

COPY $RAILS_PATH/Gemfile .
COPY $RAILS_PATH/Gemfile.lock .
COPY $RAILS_PATH/config/puma.rb config/puma.rb
COPY $RAILS_PATH/config/schedule.rb config/schedule.rb

RUN \
 gem update --system && \
 gem install bundler && \
 bundle config --global build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries && \
 bundle config --global jobs 2 && \
 bundle install --path=vendor/bundler

RUN \
 chown -R $USER $HOME && \
 chown -R $USER $APP_ROOT && \
 chgrp -R $GROUP $APP_ROOT && \
 chgrp -R $GROUP $APP_ROOT

USER $USER

RUN bundle exec whenever --update-crontab

CMD cron -f && bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb
```

...

Answer (score 1):

You could use the gem [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask) instead of whenever. It runs tasks within Rails, so the user is the same. Just reference your tasks from `config/initializers/arask.rb` instead and forget about running cron.

Comment: Thank you so much!
I will try!

Comment: I tried but seemed like it was not working. I checked logs and the created db but I couldn't see any record. Just in case, I ran `docker-compose exec app cron -l` and got `cron: can't open or create /var/run/crond.pid: Permission denied` error.

Comment: It's not running "cron". It's running inside the rails app. So if rails is running (in the container) so is your tasks.

Comment: Thanks! Will make sure if there's "cron" running by the rails user!

Comment: No I ended up putting the cron tasks in the container. And the container owns multiple docker containers like rails, db and etc.

Comment: @daicky777 do you mind to share your final result? I didn't understand what you mean with the previous comment. Thanks in advance